What is the difference between a "Complaint for Civil Protection Order" and a "Motion for Civil Protection Order"?

In the United States, in the state of Colorado, in Arapahoe County, petitioners must choose between one of two options:


"Complaint for Civil Protection Order"
"Motion for Civil Protection Order"



What is the difference between these two things?

Not sure about this specific scenario, but generally speaking, a complaint initiates a new court case, while a motion is a request for relief as part of a case that already exists.

A complaint for a civil protection order is a stand alone lawsuit seeking protection order relief outside the context of any existing court case. In a new case, a filing fee must be paid and service of process of the complaint (possibly together with an ex parte temporary protection order) is via a process server.
A motion for a civil protection order is a request for protection order relief within the context of an existing court case such as a divorce, paternity case, or some other kind of civil lawsuit. In a motion within an existing case, a new filing fee to start a case does not have to be filed and the motion can be served by mail or email or e-filing on the target of the motion's attorney, although the order granting the protection order or ex parte temporary protection order must be personally served upon the person subject to it by a process server.
Also, it is worth noting that in Colorado, there is a distinction between (1) a "protection order" of the kind requested in this form, which once entered is directly enforceable by law enforcement, and (2) a "temporarily restraining order" or "injunction" which once entered by a court is enforced, if it is breached, by bringing a contempt of court motion in the same lawsuit in which the order was entered. The grounds for a protection order are narrower and apply basically when the person against whom it is sought is a personal threat to the person seeking it. A "temporary restraining order" or "injunction" is often brought to prevent economic harm on an emergency basis (e.g. to prevent the disclosure of a trade secret, or to prevent someone from selling an asset that is under contract at far less than fair market value).
The primary statute governing Civil Protection Orders is Colorado Revised Statutes § 13-14-104.5, and anyone contemplating filing for one should read it before completing the form whose caption appears in the question. It sets forth the subtle procedural differences between motions for civil protection orders and complaints for civil protection orders.
